# plot log-scale and linear scale functions and histograms on same canvas

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a probability density function of that I can only evaluate the logarithm without running into numeric issues. I have a histogram that I would like to plot on the same canvas. However, for the histogram, I need the option `log=True` to have it plotted in log scale, wheras for the function, I can only have the logarithms of the values directly. How can I plot both on the same canvas?

Please look at this MWE for illustration of the problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import math
import numpy as np

sqrt2pi = math.sqrt(2*math.pi)
def gauss(l):
  return [ 1/sqrt2pi * math.exp(-x*x) for x in l]
def loggauss(l):
  return [ -math.log(sqrt2pi) -x*x for x in l ]

# just fill a histogram
h = [ random.gauss(0,1) for x in range(0,1000) ]
plt.hist(h,bins=21,normed=True,log=True)

# this works nicely 
xvals = np.arange(-4,4,0.1)
plt.plot(xvals,gauss(xvals),"-k")
# but I would like to plot this on the same canvas:
# plt.plot(xvals,loggauss(xvals),"-r")

plt.show()
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to plot two data sets in the same figure, on the same x-axis, but one on a log y-scale and one on a linear y-scale.  You can do this using [`twinx`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(h,bins=21,normed=True,log=True)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(xvals, loggauss(xvals), '-r')
```

[image: Figure]